# Mocked useHistory is not called in async event handler

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

### Summary

I'm writing test code for my react app, but somehow, it always fails.

My app code is very simple, there is only one button, and if it's clicked, a function `handleSubmit` is fired.

What the handler does are

- Fetching data from backend(This is async function)
- Move to `/complete` page.

### What I did

- I mocked the function fetching data from API in test code
- I mocked the `useHistory` in test code

### Note

I realized that if the line that is fetching data from API is commented out, the test will pass.

### Code

- My main app code

```
import { useFetchDataFromAPI } from '@/usecase/useFetchDataFromAPI';

  :

  const { fetchDataFromAPI } = useFetchDataFromAPI();

  :

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    // If the line below is not commented out, test will fail
    // const { id } = await fetchDataFromAPI();
    history.push(`/complete`);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Button</button>
    </>
```

- My test code

```
:

jest.mock('@/usecase/useFetchDataFromAPI', () => ({
  useFetchDataFromAPI: () => {
    return { fetchDataFromAPI: jest.fn((): number => {
        return 1;
    })}
  }
}));

const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as any,
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: mockHistoryPush,
  }),
}));

:

const renderApplicationWithRouterHistory = () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  const wrapper = render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Application />
    </Router>
  );
  return { ...wrapper, history };
};

:

describe('Test onClick handler', async () => {
  test('Submit', () => {
    const { getByText, getByRole } = renderApplication();

    const elementSubmit = getByText('Button');
    expect(elementSubmit).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(elementSubmit);
    expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler is called on button click, but because it is asynchronous, its result is not evaluated until **after** your test runs. In this particular case, you don't need the async behavior, so just use:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  history.push(`/complete`)
}
```

`testing-library` provides a method [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) for this if your handler did need to `await` something:

```
await waitFor(() => expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalled())
```

Though another simple way is to simply await a promise in your test so that the expectation is delayed by a tick:

```
fireEvent.click(elementSubmit);
await Promise.resolve();
expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalled();
```